# Auth Code Flow error - Missing required parameter(s). (grant_type)

Tags: onelogin

I am trying POST method from postman for Step 2 of Auth Code Flow.

But, I am getting the response as-

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "missing required parameter(s). (grant_type)"
}
```

I have already provided the grant_type as authorization_code.
Not able to figure out what is the problem.

Screenshot of Postman request attached along.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
grant_type=authorization_code
```

You can review the docs here:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type